# <SOLVED> TextField New Line Issue in Alert Dialog with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-alertdialog

I want to create an alert dialog with Jetpack Compose. In this alert dialog include a `TextField` component from `Compose`.

I created that alert dialog but there is a problem here that when I press enter button where is on the device keyboard to add a new line my content is moving to up.

**How can I solve this UI issue?**

*Thanks in advance.*

The Problem;

[image]

Here is my code;

```
@Composable
fun SimpleAlert(
    title: String = "Ask a Question",
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    onSubmit: (text: String) -> Unit
) {

        val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        val textHint = "Write your question..."
        val textLength = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        val isAnonymous = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }


        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = {
                onDismiss()
            },
            title = {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    Row(
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_exit),
                            contentDescription = "",
                            modifier = Modifier.
                            background(Color.Gray, CircleShape).clickable {
                                onDismiss()
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    Text(
                        text = title,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                }
            },
            text = {
                Column(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    TextField(
                        value = text.value,
                        onValueChange = {
                            if (it.length <= 200) {
                                textLength.value = it.length
                                text.value = it
                            }
                        },
                        label = {
                          Text(text = textHint)
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(top = 16.dp)
                            .sizeIn(minHeight = 120.dp)
                            .background(Color.Transparent)
                    )
                }

            },
            buttons = {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Switch(checked = isAnonymous.value, onCheckedChange = {
                            isAnonymous.value = it
                        })
                        Text(text = "Anonymously")
                    }

                    Text(text = "${textLength.value}/200")
                }
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 0.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 24.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        onSubmit(text.value)
                    }) { Text(text = "Submit") }
            }
            )
}
```

***SOLUTION*** ✅

To solve this issue just use *Dialog* instead of *AlertDialog*

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely what you are looking for

```
 TextField(
                value = text.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    if (it.length <= 200) {
                        textLength.value = it.length
                        text.value = it
                    }
                },
                label = {
                    Text(text = textHint)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 16.dp)
                    .sizeIn(minHeight = 120.dp)
                    .background(Color.Transparent),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                ),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onDone = {
                       //Do something here
                    },
                ),
            )
```